# Protect row if cell contains a text

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet to record some expenses, I shared the sheet with someone but it has  a column for my review  and I'd like to protect the row if the Columne contains "Approved".

I'd like to protect it using range protect if possible

[image: Sheet preview]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Protect approved rows**

```
function protectApprovedRows() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('name');
  var sr=2;
  var sc=1;
  var vs=sh.getRange(sr,sc,sh.getLastRow()-sr+1,sh.getLastColumn()-sc+1).getValues();
  var me = Session.getEffectiveUser(); 
  vs.forEach(function(r,i){
    if(r[4]=="Approved") {
      var protection=sh.getRange(i+sr,sc,1,sh.getLastColumn()-sc+1).protect();
      protection.addEditor(me); 
      protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors()); 
      if (protection.canDomainEdit()) { 
        protection.setDomainEdit(false); 
      }
    }
  });
}
```

[Range.Protect()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#protect())

Comment: Thanks for the script, I'm totally newbie to google scripts, I tried to use the script but still not protected , I've change the sheet name to 'Expensis' and still not protected if approved, the column is E, I can see you used r[4] as excel counts from 0. 
any suggest ?

Comment: r[4] is column E

Comment: How do you know its not protected.  It doesn't keep the owner from editing.

Comment: I've added another mail to test, I've edited the code and now it works,

but How to make to auto execute after editing E column ?

Comment: `var protection = sh.getRange(i+sr,sc,1,sh.getLastColumn()-sc+1).protect().setDescription('can not edit approved');

        // Ensure the current user is an editor before removing others. Otherwise, if the user's edit
        // permission comes from a group, the script throws an exception upon removing the group.
        var me = Session.getEffectiveUser();
        protection.addEditor(me);
        protection.removeEditors(protection.getEditors());
        if (protection.canDomainEdit()) {
          protection.setDomainEdit(false);
        }`
this is the code which I added

Comment: I did it using onEdit, Thanks for your help

Comment: **Until the script actually changes the list of editors for the range (by calling Protection.removeEditor(emailAddress), Protection.removeEditor(user), Protection.removeEditors(emailAddresses), Protection.addEditor(emailAddress), Protection.addEditor(user), Protection.addEditors(emailAddresses), or setting a new value for Protection.setDomainEdit(editable)), the permissions mirror those of the spreadsheet itself, which effectively means that the range remains unprotected. If the range is already protected**. Range.protect() doesn't protect anything.